# Compute $(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z})_x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, constraints

I came across the following question and am uncertain whether my result can be further developed (I don't really see the interest in the question, if my answer is the final form - it doesn't seem particularly revealing, as a question). **Am I missing anything?**

> Let $w = f(x,y,z)$ be a function subject to $xy = kz$, where $k$ is a
>   constant. Find $\big(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\big)_x$.

---

My attempt:

$\big(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\big)_x$ implies that we have $w = w(x,z)$ and $y = y(x,z)$. Applying the chain rule, we have:

$$ \Big(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\Big)_x 
      %
      =  \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big) \Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\Big)_x
      %
      + \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\Big), $$
where, for $x \neq 0$,  $y = k \tfrac{z}{x}$, so $\Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\Big)_x = \frac{k}{x}$, as such:

$$\Big(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\Big)_x 
      %
      =  \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big) \frac{k}{x}
      %
      + \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\Big).$$

Comment: what does the subscript $P$ or $x$ mean in this context?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 the subscript indicates the other independent variable(s). i.e. $\big(\frac{ \partial w}{ \partial z}\big)_{x}$ implies that $w = w(x,z)$ (and so $y = y(x,z)$, as well). I am not aware of any other interpretation of this notation (and am certain that that is what is meant in this case); do others exist?